# Resizing a GLKView

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios5, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

When a `GLKView` is resized, there are some behind-the-scenes operations that take place on the buffers and context of that `GLKView`. During the time it takes to perform these behind-the-scenes operations, drawing to the `GLKView` does not produce correct results.

In my scenario, I have a `GLKView` that has `setNeedsDisplay` enabled, so that anytime I need to update it's contents on screen, I just call `-setNeedsDisplay` on that 
`GLKView`. I'm using `GLKView` to draw images, so if I need to draw an image with a different size, I need to also change the size of the `GLKView`.

The problem: When I change the size of the `GLKView` and call `setNeedsDisplay` on that view, the result on screen is not correct. This is because the `GLKView` is not done finishing the behind-the-scenes operations invoked by the new size change before it tries to draw the new image.

I found a work-around to this by calling: `performSelector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0` instead of just `setNeedsDisplay` on the `GLKView`. This basically forces the main thread to wait for all the behind-the-scenes openGL operations to be completed before calling `setNeedsDisplay`. Although this works ok, I am wondering if there is a better solution. For example, is there an openGL call to make the thread wait for all openGL operations to be completed before continuing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution was to reset the `CIContext` object after the `GLKView` has been resized.

Comment: How did you reset it? Recreating it from scratch? Or is there a specific method to call.

Comment: In my case, after the resize I was setting my `CIContext` object like so: `ci_context = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:glkView.context]` and then calling `[glkView display]`. Note that this was a long time ago and I didn't pursue learning about this, so don't assume it's the right approach.